# how to add more than one items in one CTabItem?

Tags: java, swt, ctabitem

```
CTabItem tabItem1 = new CTabItem(newTabFolder, SWT.CLOSE);
tabItem1.setText("Tab 1");
Label lab2 = new Label(newTabFolder, 0);
lab2.setText("Hello World");
tabItem1.setControl(table);
tabItem1.setControl(lab2);
```

I am trying to have a `CTabItem` which has a table and some labels and textfields

But the problem arising is that any item/widget is added by use of `setControl(Control control)` function. And I cannot pass more than two controls. The code above adds a table first and then over writes it with the label, hence showing only one item at a time.

And I want both things at one time.

I have also tried to see if I might add things to an object of Control and then pass that control to `setControl()` function but I could not find any function by which I can add items/widgets to control
please tell me how to do this.

```
final Composite compositeInTab = new Composite(newTabFolder, SWT.NONE);
        compositeInTab.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        table = new Table(compositeInTab, SWT.V_SCROLL);

        btn1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
            {
                /*JUST CREATING A TABLE AND MANAGING IT*/
                String[] titles = {"System Code","Domain Name","Organizational Unit","Organization Name"};
                for(int i=0; i<titles.length; i++)
                {
                    TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER, i);
                    column.setText(titles[i]);
                    column.setWidth(150);
                    column.setMoveable(true);
                    column.setResizable(true);
                }
                for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
                {
                    TableItem item = new TableItem(table, 0);
                    item.setText(0, ""+i);
                    item.setText(1, ""+i);
                    item.setText(2, ""+i);
                    item.setText(3, ""+i);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) 
                {
                    table.getColumn(i).pack();
                }
                table.setHeaderVisible(true);
                table.setSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, 200));
                table.setLinesVisible(true);
                /*CREATING OF TABLE COMPLETE*/

                compositeForTabFolder.setLayout(new GridLayout());
                compositeForTabFolder.setBounds(280, 0, 500, 450);
                newTabFolder.setUnselectedCloseVisible(false);

                CTabItem tabItem1 = new CTabItem(newTabFolder, SWT.CLOSE);
                tabItem1.setText("Tab 1");
                Label lab2 = new Label(compositeInTab, 0);
                lab2.setText("Hello World");
                Label lab3 = new Label(compositeInTab, 0);
                lab3.setText("Bye Bye World");
                tabItem1.setControl(compositeInTab);

                newTabFolder.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 300);
            }
        });
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfHv7.png)

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. Try this mini example: http://pastebin.com/DyvxtV07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Composite`, then add everything you want to this `Composite` and afterwards use `setControl(composite)`.

This way, you will only have to add ONE widget via `setControl()` but this widget can have multiple children.

There is a good example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/PasstheCompositetothetabssetControlmethod.htm).

Here is the sample code from this site (slightly modified):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      TabItem item = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
      item.setText("TabItem " + i);
      item.setToolTipText("This is my tab" + i);

      Composite composite = new Composite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
      composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
      new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");
      new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER).setText("TextField");
      new Label(composite, SWT.NONE).setText("Label");

      Table table = new Table(composite, SWT.NONE);
      table.setHeaderVisible(true);

      new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE).setText("TableItem");

      item.setControl(composite);

    }
    tabFolder.pack();
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion worked well but for labels and buttons only
it gives error when table is added in that composite

Comment: @AsadUllah It works for me for any `Control`. Just tried it with `Text` which is what you want.

Comment: sir i want a table, labels and texts in that tabitem

Comment: @AsadUllah And what is the error you are having? It works fine for me.

Comment: the browser stops working
no error on console
can i add a picture in comments??
a screenshot of my eclipse might give you some idea
i am new to stackoverflow and i dont know whether i can add picture here or not

Comment: @AsadUllah Please add the picture to your question. However, did you try the sample code I provided? It contains a `Button`, a `Label`, a `Text` and a `Table`, which is all you mentioned.

Comment: @AsadUllah First of all: Did you try the code I provided? You can add pictures by editing your question. There is a small image icon above the text field with the tooltip "Image <img>". Use that to upload a picture.

Comment: i think my reputation is not enough to add image
and yes i am doing exactly the same thing
just a little difference that i am adding one table instead of 5 tables